# Filter data using query string parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, parameters, angular-ui-router

I have 2 files:

module.js with the following code:

```
angular.module('App.fragments.Jobs', []).
config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('jobs', {
            url: '/trabajos',
            templateUrl: '/templates/jobs/list.html',
            controller: 'JobsListCtrl'
        });
}]);
```

jobs-list-ctrl.js with the following code:

```
angular.module('App.fragments.Jobs')
.controller('JobsListCtrl', ['$scope', 'JobsListService', function ($scope, JobsListService) {
    $scope.filter = function() {
        JobsListService.loadJobs($scope.filters, function(_response) {
            console.log(_response.length, "jobs...");
        });
    };

    $scope.filter();
}]);
```

I'm accessing this through **lean.domain.com/apps/hub/noop#/trabajos**

The problem is that I want to pass params through my url like this:

I'm accessing this through **lean.domain.com/apps/hub/noop#/trabajos?param_one=value_one&param_two=value_two...**

and then, take those values in my controller to filter data using the filter method shown before.
Something like this:

```
angular.module('App.fragments.Jobs')
.controller('JobsListCtrl', ['$scope', 'JobsListService', function ($scope, JobsListService) {

    //Parse value_one&param_two=value_two from url
    //and fill $scope.filters with value like
    //{param_one: value_one, param_two: value_two}

    $scope.filter = function() {
        JobsListService.loadJobs($scope.filters, function(_response) {
            console.log(_response.length, "jobs...");
        });
    };

    $scope.filter();
}]);
```

I read about [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) and [ui-router and $stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) but I'm not sure what is the **best way** to do this and why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract what's in your query string you can you $location like this:

for this url lean.domain.com/apps/hub/noop#/trabajos?param_one=value_one&param_two=value_two, you can use $location.search() that returns the query string in JavaScript object format.

Comment: As I said, I read about $location. But, I can do the same with stateParams. So, my question is not: how to do this?, my question is: what is the best way to do this and why?